# Can I apply different styles to antd pop overs when they are in different components?

Tags: css, sass, popup, antd, css-modules

I want to apply different styles to antd pop overs when they are in different components, especially the positions where they appear. For example if I have `a` button and `b` button, I want to make a pop over appear 50px right of `a` button and the other appear 100px left of `b` button. I have no clue to do this because it seems I can not add a className in antd pop over component such as `antd-popover-title`, `antd-popover-content`, and so on. Please let me know if you have any ideas..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Popover class has the same API as Tooltip. https://ant.design/components/tooltip/#API
In there you may find multiple ways to style the popover how you want. With either overlayClassName, overlayStyle, overlayInnerStyle.
https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-fermat-izfv8?file=/index.js